# Android Firebase Prevent User From Deleting Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android project that uses firebase as online database. I realize that on database there is some values, nodes that shouldn't be there. I think someone change apk file and modify some code and writes another field in my database. How can I prevent this? Because if they can write something to any field they can also delete all my data by simply writing to my main node setValue(something).

Comment: Take a look at [Firebase security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Answer (score 0):

Use rules, a logged in user only have access to certain nodes

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Start here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart

Comment: i do use rules. you didn't understand me. for instance user can access to messages node and read or write. what if he/she changes the code and put the value of the node something and delete all messages. please don't answer before fully understanding. I said if user changes my source code. you said database rules. of course I use database rules!

Comment: And please don't just comment before understanding my answer. You don't seem to appreciate the time we put here to help you, we don't get paid to give you free help.